# Удалить дубликаты и суммировать значения нескольких столбцов MSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

```
id  name    value 1 value 2 value 3
1   cars       2     4       5
2   cars       1     1       1
3   bus1       0     53      0
4   bus1       0     0       5
5   moto       2     0       0
6   moto       0     3       0
7   moto       0     0       4
```

Как можно написать запрос? что бы вывод был на примере cars:

```
id  name    value 1 value 2 value 3
1   cars       3     5       6
```

Писал SELECT FROM SELECT, но выдавал неверные значения

Comment: обычная группировка по полю с суммированием по требуемым столбцам. покажите, как вы пытались сделать?

Comment: `select min(id), names, sum(x), ... group by name`